# Button push down effect

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to change the button background image when the button is pushed down. Can't figure it out. I've already done a button higlight effect. I'm working in Winforms.

Comment: on click just change background image with size little smaller than default one

Comment: Not the best environment to pursue graphics effects like that. If you are still able to do so, think about to switch to WPF.

Comment: I can't switch to WPF now, it's too late. Is there any way to do the push effect? Because the highlight one was pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use MouseDown and MouseUp events to change the background image of the button. it should not be harder then the highlight effect.